# Queries returning multiple result sets

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a `MSSQL` database and am running the following query:

```
select * from projects; select * from user
```

The above query returns two result sets at once, and I cannot fire both queries separately. How can I handle both the result set at once in a Java class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Correct code to process multiple `ResultSet`s returned by a JDBC statement:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = ...;
boolean isResultSet = stmt.execute();

int count = 0;
while(true) {
    if(isResultSet) {
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()) {
            processEachRow(rs);
        }

        rs.close();
    } else {
        if(stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1) {
            break;
        }

        log.info("Result {} is just a count: {}", count, stmt.getUpdateCount());
    }

    count ++;
    isResultSet = stmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

Important bits:

- `getMoreResults()` and `execute()` return `false` to indicate that the result of the statement is just a number and not a `ResultSet`.
- You need to check `stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1` to know if there are more results.
- Make sure you either close the result sets or use `stmt.getMoreResults(Statement.CLOSE_CURRENT_RESULT)`

Comment: In this answer I'm missing where stmt comes from. I realise stmt is a Prepared Statement, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Statement.execute(), getResultSet();

```
PreparedStatement stmt = ... prepare your statement result
boolean hasResults = stmt.execute();
while (hasResults) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    ... your code parsing the results ...
    hasResults = stmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

Comment: This misinterprets the meaning of the `boolean` return value: `true` means the next result is a `ResultSet`, while `false` means the next result is an update count (or, when the update count is `-1`, that there are no more results). This can happen especially on SQL Server (and Sybase) where result sets and update counts can be emitted from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can. See this MSDN article
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378758(v=sql.110).aspx

```
public static void executeStatement(Connection con) {
   try {
      String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Person.Contact; " +
                   "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Person.Contact";
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      boolean results = stmt.execute(SQL);
      int rsCount = 0;

      //Loop through the available result sets.
     do {
        if(results) {
           ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
           rsCount++;

           //Show data from the result set.
           System.out.println("RESULT SET #" + rsCount);
           while (rs.next()) {
              System.out.println(rs.getString("LastName") + ", " + rs.getString("FirstName"));
           }
           rs.close();
        }
        System.out.println();
        results = stmt.getMoreResults();
        } while(results);
      stmt.close();
      }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

I've tested that and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void executeProcedure(Connection con) {
   try {
      CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(...);
      .....  //Set call parameters, if you have IN,OUT, or IN/OUT parameters

      boolean results = stmt.execute();
      int rsCount = 0;

      //Loop through the available result sets.
     while (results) {
           ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
           //Retrieve data from the result set.
           while (rs.next()) {
        ....// using rs.getxxx() method to retrieve data
           }
           rs.close();

        //Check for next result set
        results = stmt.getMoreResults();
      } 
      stmt.close();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: This misinterprets the meaning of the `boolean` return value: `true` means the next result is a `ResultSet`, while `false` means the next result is an update count (or, when the update count is `-1`, that there are no more results). This can happen especially on SQL Server (and Sybase) where result sets and update counts can be emitted from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Before use java, you need look at the RESULT SETS clause.

MSSQL has this feature that can help you with your java code, in a more practical way.

This example will exec two queries:

```
EXEC('SELECT id_person, name, age FROM dbo.PERSON; SELECT id_url, url FROM dbo.URL;')
WITH RESULT SETS
(
  (
    id_person BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    age TINYINT
  ),
  (
    id_url BIGINT,
    url VARCHAR(2000)
  )
);
```

You can use stored procedures with RESULT SETS as well.

More about: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score -4):

The UNION ALL query allows you to combine the result sets of 2 or more "select" queries. It returns all rows (even if the row exists in more than one of the "select" statements).

Each SQL statement within the UNION ALL query must have the same number of fields in the result sets with similar data types.........

```
select * from projects
UNION ALL
select * from user
```

Comment: Hi All,

Basically what i want is: "Just is there any way to handle two ResultsSets simultaneously in a query or not". ??

Comment: Hi All,

Basically what i want is: "Just is there any way to handle two ResultsSets simultaneously in a query or not". ?? yes or no. . if yes then how in the java code. .??. .

Answer (score -25):

The answer: it is *NOT* possible. The only way: Run them as separate queries.

Comment: JDBC supports multiple results sets