# Return values from DB with another result set

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset, postgresql-9.4

How can I execute this statement and process it java. Is it possible to get a return value and then the next resultset which is the select to employee in the way I'm doing it?

I cannot find the accurate way on Google to perform what I want because all of the examples are results with single SELECTs and cannot find a query with RETURN from DB. But according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696572/queries-returning-multiple-result-sets), it is possible to manage multiple result sets from DB (java) as .NET can do.

I'm using postgresql 9.4 and I don't want to use a stored proc (function) to do what I'm trying to do.

This is the code that I've been trying to test, but I get an exception that there is a syntax error in 'IF' line 1

```
public Employee getEmployee(Connection con, String code) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    try {
        String query = 
                "IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM employee WHERE code = ?) THEN "
                + "RETURN 1; "
                + "ELSE "
                + "RETURN 2; "
                + "END IF; "
                + "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName FROM employee where code = ?; ";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, code);
        stmt.setString(2, code);
        boolean hasResults = stmt.execute();
        int returnValue = 0;
        while(hasResults){
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
            returnValue = rs.getInt(1);
            if(returnValue == 1){
                hasResults = stmt.getMoreResults();
                while(hasResults){
                    employee.setId(rs.getInt("EmployeeID"));
                    employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                }
            }
        }
        return employee;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things (apart from the fact that there is no `if` in SQL).

Just run the select, if there is no such employee you'll get an empty result set:

```
public Employee getEmployee(Connection con, String code) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName FROM employee where code = ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, code);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            employee.setId(rs.getInt("EmployeeID"));
            employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
        }
        return employee;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

You also might want to move the creation of the `Employee` instance inside the `if (rs.next())` so that if no employee exists your method returns null. The above code would always return an `Employee` even if there is none

---

You also should remove the `;` from the query string. Although the Postgres driver will happily run statements terminated with `;` this is not JDBC compliant and other drivers (or DBMS) might refuse to run it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. My question was an example. In any way how can I get the return value followed by a query. I want to execute mutiple queries and get the multiple result sets in just one transaction/execution. But at the same time I wanna be able to perform function but not specifically pre-compiled in the DBMS, but as query string.