# Difference in SQL native and JDBC when used while-begin-end loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jdbc

At the execution of a small t-sql loop (while - begin - end) in native MSSQL connection and JDBC getting a strange results. 
In MSSQL SMS all works as expected where via JDBC getting just the first loop.

```
declare @i int = 1
while @i <= 10
  begin
    select @i
    set @i=(@i+1)
  end
```

Result in SMS is:
        1
        2
3
...
10

Where in via jdbc just 
1

Highly appreciate any help !

Thank you

Comment: You could try putting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of the batch and see if that helps. (Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189837.aspx).)

Comment: Thank you but ... didn't help

Comment: Are you checking for multiple result sets, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9696572/2144390)?

Comment: Hi Gord, I'm creating a temp table, then need to update several rows regarding the values in the temp table i.e.

Comment: {select 
 rank() over (order by table.date) as id 
 ,id
 ,entrance_date as to_date
 ,entrance_date as from_date
 ,last_id as ll_id
into #tmp
from table

where (some filter)

declare @i int, @n int

select @i = min(id), @n = max(id) from #tmp
while @i <= @n
begin

update #tmp  
   set from_date = (select top 1 ...where ... order)
 ,ll_id = (select top 1 ...where ... order)
  set @i = @i+1
end
select * from #tmp}

Comment: Please show the Java code you use.

Comment: Hi Mark, there is not java code. It's a pure SQL via jdbc connectivity used by Jasper reports.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
int size = 1
while(rs.next()){ 
     if(rs != null){

        rs.beforeFirst();  
        rs.last();  
        size = rs.getRow();  

     }

     System.out.println("cols = " + size);
}
```

Comment: Hi Raghu, that will require a code change where I'm not allowed. The Q is executed in <![CDATA[ ... ]]> as a regular tsql script