# JDBI - two Results sets - how to map them ?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbi

For this purpose lets assume that I'm using procedure:

```
exec test
```

Where test procedure return more than ONE result set. In JDBC I will use approach that is proposed in this tread [Queries returning multiple result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696572/queries-returning-multiple-result-sets) - and it works fine.

Question is is there any option to map this using JDBI into object ? If I use such approach in DOA class:

```
@SqlQuery("exec test")
@RegisterBeanMapper(UserMapper.class)
List<TestModel> getTests();
```

Only the first result set will be mapped second won't be even touch ? Any ideas here

Comment: Of course @RegisterBeanMapper(TestModel.class) looks like this :)

Comment: At this time, Jdbi does not provide any support for multiple result sets from a single statement. You will need to drop down down JDBC to read both result sets.